# Typescript syntax error when Consuming Google Map Geocoding API

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, typescript-typings

I'm working with Ionic3 and I'm consuming the Google Map Geocoding Google Map Geocoding API and I found a syntax error in this line :

```
result = data.results[1].formatted_address;
Error: Property results does not exist in type Object
```

I've resolved this issue using a dirty solution and I'm asking is there someone to give us a better Solution.

My Solution is to create an interface before my provider class in the same file and getting from subscribe data2 which I have casted and assign to variable data.

## providers/rest/rest.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

interface data {
  'results':[
    {
      "address_components": Object[],
      "formatted_address" : string,
    }
  ]
};


@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {
  apiUrl1 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=';//36.731470384526965,10.210593179614534
  apiUrl2 = '&key=AIzaSyBtYmf_L2ESZVcnkeIHRw_uD0VQIBbFYAM';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
  }

  getCity(latLng) {
    let apiUrl = this.apiUrl1+latLng.lat()+','+latLng.lng()+this.apiUrl2;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(apiUrl).subscribe(data2 => {
        let result ='';
        let data: data;
        data = <data>data2;
        if(data && data.results[1])
          result = data.results[1].formatted_address;
        else 
          result = 'Undefinied city'
        resolve(result);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is just a compilation warning/error being shown to you by your editor. 
You can declare **data2 as of type any**, which will not cause tsc compiler to cause errors. You will not have to define any interface for this either. Do as below:

`this.http.get(apiUrl).subscribe((data2: any) => {//your implementation}`

But, I suggest using the interface is a good idea as it will let your tests know what kind of object to expect when you call that api. Ideally if I knew the type of the response from api I would define an interface like you did and have the data2 of the type of that interface like:

```
interface IData {
  'results':[    
    {
      "address_components": Object[],
      "formatted_address" : string,
    }
  ]
};
```

`this.http.get(apiUrl).subscribe((data2: IData) => {//your implementation}`

Refer to this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajtf3u)